# Spring boot java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there any reason why would adding dependencies cause error? Before adding them application is running normally.

After adding these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.176</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the following error while running application in STS:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.<clinit>(JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.java:65) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfigureRegistrar.getRepositoryConfigurationExtension(JpaRepositoriesAutoConfigureRegistrar.java:49) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:352) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at com.hellokoding.springboot.WebApplication.main(WebApplication.java:30) [classes/:na] 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>hello-springboot</artifactId>
<name>hello-springboot</name>
<description>hello-springboot</description>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.176</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Web jars -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `spring-orm` version you are declaring doesn't match with your spring-boot version. 
You should remove `spring-orm`'s dependency and let spring-boot include the appropriate version through `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

remove this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You should also remove h2's version, which is provided by Spring-Boot too (keep the dependency, just not the version).

---

You could also update your spring boot version (to move up the dependency versions), but in all cases, the dependencies mentioned above may be removed.

Comment: When i remove it in Problems tab i get an error that says `Class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor' not found` and when i run application it shows the same error as before.

Comment: @dzontra91 Make sure to rebuild your project. Also, you should be able to remove the `<version>1.3.176</version>` from the H2 dependency because Spring can also manage that.

Comment: Thank you guys, but the problem was with version in parent dependency. When i changed version to 1.3.8 there was no error anymore.

Comment: It's the same reason, and you fixed it the other way around. You should still remove the spring-orm and h2 spelt and let spring-boot-starter provide them for you. Anyhow, you don't have the error anymore, that's what matters!

Comment: Same issue with 2.0.0.RC1

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue with 1.5.9 version and going back to 1.5.0 version of spring fixed the issue